# How to mount a volume to your Docker Image on a Gitlab Runner? (gitlab-ci.yml)

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've running a Docker image for browser testing setup on my gitlab runner. This is specified in a gitlab-ci.yml like so:

```
test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: mysql:5.7
      alias: mysql-test
  image: chilio/laravel-dusk-ci:stable
  script:
    - cp .env.ci .env
      ...
```

Now, when I run multiple tests, the first ones succeed and the rest fails. It seems this might be related to the shared memory, according to this issue: [elgalu/docker-selenium#20](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/20). I've already increased the shm_size setting on the gitlab runner itself, however I think I need to mount the docker image's shm folder to the runner's shm folder. Normally I would specify this in a docker-compose.yml or on the commandline like so:

```
docker run -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm
```

However I can't figure out how to do this in the `gitlab-ci.yml`. On the `image` key you can only specify a `name` and `entrypoint`... [as documented here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#available-settings-for-image)

**The question is:** Can anyone tell me how mount the folder?

ps: for those interested, this is the error:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchDriverException: invalid session id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your configuration of your gitlab runner to [increase shm size](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section)

For instance:
shm_size = 300000

Comment: I did that, but I dont think that does increase the available shared memory on my docker image?

Comment: According to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/merge_requests/468 it should work and make dockers images use shared host memory?